# Passing Variables in an Array

Tags: perl, mechanize

I have the code below which is supposed to click and go to each link with the text... What is happening is that `$l` stays the letter A, and collects the page for A 26x ... Any ideas?

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($info->website);

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new();
my @abc = ("A" .. "Z");

foreach my $letter (@abc){

$mech->find_link(text => $letter);
$mech->follow_link(text => $letter);

$content = $mech->content();

$te->parse($content);

$table = $te->first_table_found;

$str .= Dumper $table;

$mech->back();
}
```

Comment: You are mistaken, as you can see by adding `print "$l\n";`

Comment: I should have further explained. I did print $l to see if it was working and, yes, it does print the alphabet as expected. but I put the contents of the $table in a temp file and if I look at that temp file I see 26 instances of page A, it does not collect data from any other pages... seems like it stays on page A...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that HTMLTableExtract was not getting the new data. Moved the TE initialization into the loop $te->parse($content) was overwriting what it already had.

Comment: If I print it prints the alphabet, but this $mech->follow_link(text => $l); does not get the variable it says A

Comment: yes, if I print out using print $l, I get the alphabet, but if I look at the temp file that I am putting the content in, I get 26 instances of page A, it does not go to the other pages....

Comment: Ok, so the problem is not the foreach not working correctly. The problem is in some way related to something with Mech. 1) Can you post the complete code here or pastebin and a link to the page you are trying to link from or the source for the page? The first rule of troubleshooting is to accurately define the problem. You are not there yet.

Comment: code posted above... the page I am going to is just a page with links from A - Z and I checked and they all work... this code worked when I used Win32::IEAutomation but I was getting to many OLE errors so I am attempting to convert it... the code was originally written without a foreach and just individually clicking A, B, C, etc.. I am attempting to take this code and make it more efficient...

Comment: $content is not changing... I tried changing A to 1 and get an error that it can not find the link on the page, so it is finding the link, and following the first one, finding the second link, but not following it and collecting data from the same page...

Answer (score 0):

After following a link, you have to go back to the original page to have all the links available again. Just add

```
$mech->back;
```

to the end of the loop.